# How to resolve Rubocop error 'Favor `format` over `String#%`'

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I am trying generate the mac address using following code, but robocop is throwing a warning

```
mac_address = format((1..6).map { '%0.2X' % rand(256) } .join(':'))
```

Following is the warning, kindly suggest that I solve this

```
Favor `format` over `String#%`. (convention:Style/FormatString)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just change

```
mac_address = format((1..6).map { '%0.2X' % rand(256) } .join(':'))
```

to

```
mac_address = (1..6).map { format('%0.2X', rand(256)) } .join(':')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code example in your question does not use the `format` for anything:

```
format((1..6).map { '%0.2X' % rand(256) } .join(':'))
```

The `format` is called with the output of:

```
(1..6).map { '%0.2X' % rand(256) } .join(':')
=> "AB:CD:EF:01:02:03"
```

Which is the same as doing something like:

```
format("AB:CD:EF:01:02:03")
```

Which does essentially nothing to the string.

Just change it to:

```
(1..6).map { '%0.2X' % rand(256) } .join(':')
```

Or:

```
format("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", *(1..6).map { rand(256) })
```

Or:

```
format((['%02X'] * 6).join(':'), *(1..6).map { rand(256) })
```

You're getting the error message because you're mixing both `format` and `%` (eventhough the `format` is doing nothing). Rubocop likely wants you to use one or the other, not both.